# Show that $U$ is a subspace of $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $U = \{(a_1, a_2, . . . , a_n, . . . )\in V| \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_{i}^2\}$ is finite. Prove that $U$ is a subspace of $V$ where $V$ is a vector space over $F$, the field of real number.
My attempt:

let $X, Y \in U$ and $\alpha , \beta \in F$  where $X=(x_1, x_2, . . . , x_n, . . .)$ and $Y=(y_1, y_2, . . ., y_n, . . .)$
We have $\sum_{i=0}^\infty (\alpha x_i + \beta y_i) = \alpha^2\sum_{i=0}^\infty x_{i}^2 + 2\alpha\beta \sum_{i=0}^\infty {x_i}{y_i} + \beta^2 \sum_{i=0}^infty y_{i}^2$. 
So how can I show that $\sum_{i=0}^\infty {x_i}{y_i}$ is finite? Its clear that other two term is finite. Or is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: Capitals at the beginning of a sentence seems to be a hard concept for some people...

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: What is $V$? I don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bound $\sum_i a_i b_i$, we can use cauchy schwarz: $|\langle u,v \rangle|^2 \leq \langle u, u\rangle \cdot \langle v, v\rangle $.

We introduce the inner product over $U$: $\langle ~,~\rangle: U \times U \rightarrow \mathbb R: ~\langle\{a_i\}, \{b_i\}\rangle \equiv \sum_i a_i b_i$.

One can check that this is indeed an inner product and that it satisfies the axioms (bilinearity and symmetry).

Hence, we can use cauchy-schwarz. to get the bound:

$$
|\langle \{a_i\}, \{b_i\}\rangle|^2 
\le
 \langle\{a_i\}, \{a_i\}\rangle \cdot 
 \langle\{b_i\}, \{b_i\}\rangle \\
\left( \sum_i a_ib_i \right)^2 \leq \left( \sum_i a_i^2 \right) \left( \sum_i b_i^2 \right)
$$

Since we know that $\sum_i a_i^2$ and $\sum_i b_i^2$ are bounded, this lets us derive that $\sum_i a_i b_i$ is also bounded.